# How to set a default namespace for classes when there are two similar classes in different namespaces

Tags: .net, visual-studio, namespaces, conflict

Ok, so since going to version 2.5 Nunit is causing me all sorts of problems because they introduced the static class **Is** into the nunit.framework namespace.

It would be well and good if Rhino.Mocks and a few other frameworks did not also make use of an **Is** static class.  So now if I upgrade to 2.5 most of my code that uses rhino mocks constraints will not compile.

Is there a way to configure visual studio/the c# compiler on the project level to know that when I say **Is** I mean the Rhino Mocks namespace?

PS. Open Source authors, I know you love da fluent interfaces but stop using such common words when they're going to clash with other frameworks!  How about some closures with lambdas you can still do something like myVar.Should(be=>be.True())?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the NUmit context but maybe the alias mechanism can help you:

```
namespace N1
{
  class C { }
}

namespace N2
{
    class C { }
}

namespace NamespaceDemos
{
    using C1 = N1.C;
    using C2 = N2.C;
}
```

Comment: See my response to @McWafflestix that is valid going forward but not to get rid of the incomparability that breaks my project.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [using alias directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive) at the top of your files to make unqualified references to `Is` point to the Rhino type.

```
using Is = Rhino.Mocks.Constraints.Is;
```

Unfortunately I don't think there's a way to do this at the project-level. But this is at least better than searching & replacing all your references.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the `using` directive.

Comment: No good, I already have code using Rhino Mocks Is.  NUnit though added the Is class to its base directory.  I would have to go through my codebase adding an alias before I have used the rhino mocks Is.  Might as well write my own extension at that point.

Comment: I know this sounds silly, but have you tried just doing a global search and replace to replace it with the fully qualified name?

Comment: Well..yes that would work, but then I have to fully qualified Rhino Mocks Is classes (which I use a lot) just so that Nunit can have its "Is" class (which I don't use at all)...ugly